# How can I increment a cell referenced in a script each time I run it?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this script, which works perfectly (although I'm sure there's a better way to do this).

```
function dataTransfer() {
   var value1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('BACKLOG').getRange('G18').getValue();
   var value2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('BACKLOG').getRange('AF8').getValue();
   var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('AM COMP');
   var cell1 = sheet2.getRange('D8');
   var cell2 = sheet2.getRange('D18');
   cell1.setValue(value1);
   cell2.setValue(value2);

}
```

This code reads cells for data and copies that data to another sheet when I press a button I created. What I need is for the cells that I'm getting data from and putting data into to change (some by an increment of 2 rows over, some by 1) each time I run the script.

For example: in January I press the button and the value in G18 (BACKLOG) is copied to D8 (AM COMP), the value in AF8 (BACKLOG) gets copied to D18 (AM UPSELL). But in February I would like to push the button again but this time have the value from I18 (BACKLOG) copied to E8 (AM COMP), AF8 (BACKLOG) stays the same but gets copied to E18 (AM COMP). For March they would need to move again, etc.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be a complete solution, but it should give you an idea of what needs to be done.  You need to fill in the values for the rest of the months in the object literal.

```
function dataTransfer() {
  var addr_2_ToGet,cellAddressToGet,cellAddressToSet,
      currentMonthNumber,d,innerObj,objectMap,sourceSheet,ss;

  d = new Date();//Get the current date

  currentMonthNumber = d.getMonth();//Get a number which represents 
    //the current month - 0 = January
  Logger.log('currentMonthNumber: ' + currentMonthNumber)

  objectMap = {
    0:{cellToGet:'G18',cellTwoToGet:'',cellToSet:'D8',cellTwoToSet:''},
    1:{cellToGet:'I18',cellToSet:'E8'},
    2:{cellToGet:'',cellToSet:''},
    3:{cellToGet:'',cellToSet:''},
    4:{cellToGet:'',cellToSet:''},
    5:{cellToGet:'',cellToSet:''},
    6:{cellToGet:'',cellToSet:''},
    7:{cellToGet:'',cellToSet:''},
    8:{cellToGet:'',cellToSet:''},
    9:{cellToGet:'',cellToSet:''},
    10:{cellToGet:'',cellToSet:''},
    11:{cellToGet:'',cellToSet:''}    
  }

  innerObj = objectMap[currentMonthNumber]
  Logger.log('innerObj: ' + innerObj)

  cellAddressToGet = innerObj.cellToGet;
  Logger.log('cellAddressToGet: ' + cellAddressToGet)
  addr_2_ToGet = innerObj.cellTwoToGet;

  cellAddressToSet = innerObj.cellToSet;
  Logger.log('cellAddressToSet: ' + cellAddressToSet)

  addr_2_To_Set = innerObj.cellTwoToSet;
  Logger.log('addr_2_To_Set: ' + addr_2_To_Set)

  ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName('BACKLOG');

  var value1 = sourceSheet.getRange(cellAddressToGet).getValue();
  var value2 = sourceSheet.getRange(addr_2_ToGet).getValue();

  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName('AM COMP');

  var cell1 = sheet2.getRange(cellAddressToSet);
  var cell2 = sheet2.getRange(addr_2_To_Set );

  cell1.setValue(value1);
  cell2.setValue(value2);

}
```

Comment: Awesome. I finished the values in the object literal. After running the script and checking the log I can see that it is getting month 1 (Feb) but still enters the data in D8 instead of E8. Am I missing something?

Comment: I made a couple more changes.  There was an error, and I added a fourth setting.  It still might not be perfect.  But, see what you can do with it.  You'll need to add two more key/value pairs to all the other months.  I think that's what you need.  Just try to understand what the code is doing, and see if it makes sense.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going through line by line very slowly to learn and understand what is going on. Thank you very much!

Comment: @GiuseppeBaldi It would be easier for you to maintain it if you could load the object values from a spreadsheet then you could make changes without having to mess with the function. That sort of idea normally leads me to make my objects a little more granular than necessary to accomodate future needs.

Answer (score 1):

## Monthly Data Transfers

All of your settings for each month are neatly stashed away in the sheet named 'DATA'.

```
function dataTransfer() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var dataSh=ss.getSheetByName('DATA');
  var m=new Date().getMonth()+1;//The + 1 is to get past the header row
  var values=dataSh.getRange(1,1,dataSh.getLastRow(),dataSh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var hdrA=values[0];
  var valA=values[m];
  var vObj={};
  for(var i=0;i<valA.length;i++){
    vObj[hdrA[i]]=valA[i];//the hdrA is the key and the valA is the value
  }
  ss.getSheetByName(vObj.SH).getRange(vObj.RG1).setValue(ss.getSheetByName(vObj.valSH1).getRange(vObj.valRG1).getValue());
  ss.getSheetByName(vObj.SH).getRange(vObj.RG2).setValue(ss.getSheetByName(vObj.valSH2).getRange(vObj.valRG2).getValue());
  Logger.log('SH: %s,RG1: %s,valSH1: %s,valRG1: %s,RG2:%s,valSH2: %s,valRG2: %s,MONTH: %s',vObj.SH,vObj.RG1,vObj.valSH1,vObj.valRG1,vObj.RG2,vObj.valSH2,vObj.valRG2,vObj.MONTH);
}
```

This is what the 'DATA' sheet looks like:

[image]

Of course I just filled the table in with the data that you provided for one month and I added the month column.  You can add more columns and then give them a name in the header row and that will become the key for extracting in out of vObj.